# How to build a regular expression in Javascript that matches 1,234.56 1.234,56 1234.56 and 1234,56?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression that matches the numbers with "," and "." as delimiters of thousands and decimals respectively and vice versa.

1. 1,234.56
2. 1.234,56
3. **1234.56**
4. **1234,56**

This regular expression:

```js
/^(\d{1,3}(?:([,\.])\d{3}){1}(?:\2\d{3})*|\d+)(?:(?!\2)[,\.](\d*))?$/
```

matches 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4.

What I try to do is capture the thousands delimiter and prevent it from being used as a decimal delimiter. So, if the delimiter of thousands is "," then the decimal delimiter have to be ".", and if the delimiter of thousands is "." decimal delimiter have to be ",". But then I can't match numbers that don't have thousands delimiter. I think it's because the thousands delimiter catch group is null.

How can the regular expression be constructed to match the four cases?

Comment: What about `\d{1,3}(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)\b(?![.,])`? Also, `{1}` is redundant.

Comment: The point is that this backreference based approach won't work in ECMAScript powered regex because each backreference is initialized with an empty string. In PCRE, the backreference is NULL before the group matches, and once it is matched, the value is there. So, you need to re-consider the logic. It appears to me that you want to fail numbers like `10,000,00000`. Try `/^(?!\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+,(?:\d{1,2}|\d{4,})$)(?!\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+\.(?:\d{1,2}|\d{4,})$)(\d{1,3}(?=([,.]))(?:\2\d{3})*|\d+)(?:[,.](\d*))?$/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Bjpi5/1). It looks too hacky though.

Comment: I think the easiest for you (assuming lookbehinds are viable for you) is to use `(?<![\d,.])\d{1,3}?(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)(?![\d,.])` and if you can just anchor it to start/end of line `^\d{1,3}?(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)$`

Comment: What about 1,234,567.890?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\d{1,3}?(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)
```

What you'll need to add to properly match is anchors, but this depends on your use-case.

---

#### Anchor start/end of line

If you're just anchoring to the start/end of the line, you can use the following:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ssJcF0/3)

```
^\d{1,3}?(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)$
^ anchors to start of line    |    anchors to end of line ^
```

```js
x = [
  // should match:
  '1,234.56',
  '1.234,56',
  '1234.56',
  '1234,56',
  '1.2',
  '1',
  '1234',
  // should not match:
  'My number is: 1,234.56 <- this is my number',
  '1,234,56',
  '10,000,0000'
]

r = /^\d{1,3}?(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)$/

for (s of x) {
  m = s.match(r)
  console.log(m ? m[0] : 'no match')
}
```

---

#### Anchor in string (ECMA2018+)

And if you need to anchor within a string (not specifically start/end of line), you can use the following (note that it'll work in V8 engine/ECMA2018+ only since it uses lookbehind):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ssJcF0/2)

```
(?<![\d,.])\d{1,3}?(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)(?![\d,.])
^^^^^^^^^^^ ensures no \d,. precedes   |   ensures no \d,. proceeds ^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
x = [
  // should match:
  '1,234.56',
  '1.234,56',
  '1234.56',
  '1234,56',
  '1.2',
  '1',
  '1234',
  'My number is: 1,234.56 <- this is my number',
  // should not match:
  '1,234,56',
  '10,000,0000'
]

r = /(?<![\d,.])\d{1,3}?(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?)(?![\d,.])/

for (s of x) {
  m = s.match(r)
  console.log(m ? m[0] : 'no match')
}
```

---

#### Anchor in string (backwards compatible)

And if you need to anchor within a string (not specifically start/end of line), but need to maintain compliance with pre-ECMA2018 JavaScript engines:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ssJcF0/10)

```
(?:^|[^\d,.])(\d{1,3}?(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?))(?![\d,.])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ensures start of line or that no \d,. precedes
```

```js
x = [
  // should match:
  '1,234.56',
  '1.234,56',
  '1234.56',
  '1234,56',
  '1.2',
  '1',
  '1234',
  'My number is: 1,234.56 <- this is my number',
  // should not match:
  '1,234,56',
  '10,000,0000'
]

r = /(?:^|[^\d,.])(\d{1,3}?(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?))(?![\d,.])/

for (s of x) {
  m = s.match(r)
  console.log(m ? m[1] : 'no match')
}
```

---

#### Maintaining OP's capture groups

As mentioned in the comments below my answer, the above patterns don't maintain the OP's original groups. The following pattern can be used to replace the original answer in my question to keep the respective groups (just anchor it appropriately as I previously noted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ssJcF0/13)

```
^(\d{1,3}(?=([,.])?)(?:(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?!,?\d+))|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?!\.?\d+)))[,.]?(\d*)?$
```

Code below based on start/end of line anchors:

```js
x = [
  // should match:
  '1,234.56',
  '1.234,56',
  '1234.56',
  '1234,56',
  '1.2',
  '1',
  '1234',
  // should not match:
  'My number is: 1,234.56 <- this is my number',
  '1,234,56',
  '10,000,0000'
]

r = /^(\d{1,3}(?=([,.])?)(?:(?:(?:,?\d{3})*(?!,?\d+))|(?:\.?\d{3})*(?!\.?\d+)))[,.]?(\d*)?$/

for (s of x) {
  m = s.match(r)
  console.log(m ? m : 'no match')
}
```

Comment: Note that you have left out the capturing groups. If OP wants to keep them, this approach won't help and code will need adjusting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but it wouldn't be possible to preserve the third capture group regardless with JS alone unless a library was used since something like duplicate subpattern group numbers aren't available in JS engine `(?|...)`. Not without having to create some absurd regex with lookaheads.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated my answer to include an alternative with appropriate group matching based on OP's original pattern state.

Comment: Yours and OP's are not equivalent, Group 1 should only contain number before the decimal separator.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right, I misread that, my apologies - updated.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that [your regex just **fails in JS**](https://regex101.com/r/pXgjmm/1) but [seems to **work in PCRE**](https://regex101.com/r/pXgjmm/2) and [**Python**](https://regex101.com/r/pXgjmm/3).

A workaround idea can be to [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) the decimal sign inside a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as first step.

```
^(?:(?=.*([.,]))\d(?:\d{0,2}(?:(?!\1)[.,]\d{3})*|\d*)\1)?\d+$
```

[See this JS demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SQSyKp/5)

Referring to your pattern, assuming you want to match

1. `123` no decimal sign at all
2. `123.12` if decimal sign: One or more characters after the decimal point
3. `123.123,12` if thousands separator, it must be different to decimal point

I am not sure why your current pattern does not work with JS. It looks like the difference occurs in the optional last part `(?:(?!\2)[,\.](\d*))?$` with strings where `\2` does not hold a capture (has not been set). If you removed the `(?!\2)` for testing (the pattern would not work anymore as desired) [it would match](https://regex101.com/r/pXgjmm/4). Just noticed that [**@WiktorStribiżew** already made a more revealing comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381821/how-to-build-a-regular-expression-in-javascript-that-matches-1-234-56-1-234-56-1#comment104955919_59381821) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

`(?:(?:,?(?:\d){1,3})+\.(?:\d\d)\b)|(?:(?:\.?(?:\d){1,3})+\,(?:\d\d)\b)`

Two patterns in reality. One selects one format, when coma is used for decimals, and the other side selects when the dots separates decimals. Explanation:

Dot as decimal separator: `(?:(?:,?(?:\d){1,3})+\.(?:\d\d)\b)`

Coma as decimal separator: `(?:(?:\.?(?:\d){1,3})+\,(?:\d\d)\b)`

Decimal parts: `\.(?:\d\d)\b` or `\,(?:\d\d)\b`

Integer part: `(?:,?(?:\d){1,3})+\.` or `(?:\.?(?:\d){1,3})+\,`

As you can see, both are the same. It's not perfect, but it's a start.

Comment: Sorry, but it is far from the start. OP regex *is* a start, and is a much more advanced pattern, the only problem is that it works in engines other than ECMAScript one. That is what OP seeks, a JS compliant equivalent.

Comment: What are you talking about? This is 100% JS compliant pattern.

Comment: Yes, but you are not answering *this* question.

Comment: Ah, true. He wants to be able to choose 1 format or the other when used comas or dots for decimals/separator. Challenge accepted!

Comment: I'm more happy now.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise not trying to "pile-up" everything in a single RegEx as it will become unreadable and less maintainable. Valid numbers are either,

- *a)* Delimited with a dot, and there are no dots before, this is `/(?<!.).*\.\d\d$/g`, or
- *b)* Delimited with a comma, and there are no commas before, this is `(?<!,).*\,\d\d$/g`

A number is valid if `a && b`.

*For more info on 'negative lookbehind' used in the regex see: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html*